# Logged in user and AMP

Tags: amp-html

I'm doing research on AMP for my company and it seems like a good fit for anonymous users coming to our website. For logged in users, who have most of our assets already cached and service worker installed AMP, with all it's limitations, doesn't seem to make much sense.

I know about AMP-PWA and amp-access, but I don't see how I can serve a full featured PWA to the logged in user coming from Google w/o forcing them to go through an AMP document. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: We use AMP Form: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form. What limitations do you see with that service?

Comment: @JayGray I'm talking about AMP limitations overall - simple AMP document is fine for anonymous users, but for logged in ones we would like to show a full featured PWA. Unfortunately, it looks like once we release AMP documents, both anonymous and logged in users coming from Google will get AMP.

Comment: I'm missing your point. We have an AMP site. Some of the pages require users to be registered and login to access content. Is that the use case to which you are referring? Or are you making another point that I don't yet get.

Comment: @JayGray lack of custom JS in AMP makes it very limited. It's perfect for simple sites, but for highly dynamic sites/apps it's not a good match. We are fine with serving a simplified version of a page to our anonymous users (AMP), but for logged in ones we would like to show a full featured app (PWA). However, once we deploy AMP to production, all users coming from Google search results will see an AMP document. Unless, and that's my question, there is a way to somehow change it?

Comment: I haven't seen Stackoverflow using AMP. This might tell you that it's not a simple way to distinguish between anonymous and logged-in users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With amp-list and amp-bind you can build logged-in experiences.

Unfortunately there is no way to send users to your PWA conditionally based on install state since the referring platform has no insight into that.